# problem of conversion from a String to an arrayList in java

Tags: java

I've got a problem! I'm trying to convert a String to an ArrayList but it does'nt work,
it says in the console that Type mismatch : cannot convert from list to ArrayList
my little program :

```
package nfa032.application;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class ArrayListUtils {

public static void AfficherArrayListString(ArrayList<String>a) 
{
    for(int i=1; i<=a.size(); i++)
    { 
    System.out.println(a.get(i));
    }
}

public static ArrayList<String> lireArrayListString(int n) throws IOException
{
    InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(isr);
    String s;
    String [] str;
    ArrayList liste=new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)

    {
        System.out.println("Entrer une chaîne.");
        s=in.readLine();
        str=s.split("\\s+");
        liste=Arrays.asList(str);       
     }
     return liste;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is this line `liste=Arrays.asList(str);`

It's because you are trying to assign an interface `List` to an implementation of that interface which is `ArrayList`

To solve this you can do `List<String> liste=new ArrayList<String>();`

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with the code you have.

- Your `liste` variable doesn't have a diamond operator specified `ArrayList` should be `ArrayList<String>` to indicate that it will contain String elements (for more info on diamond operators https://www.baeldung.com/java-diamond-operator)
- `Arrays.asList()` does not return an `ArrayList<>`, but it returns a `List<>` (The super type of ArrayList). If you want to use `Arrays.asList`, you need to change the type of `liste` to `List<String>`

Code becomes something like this

```
public static void AfficherArrayListString(final ArrayList<String> a) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= a.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(a.get(i));
    }
}

public static List<String> lireArrayListString(final int n) throws IOException {
    final InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String s;
    String[] str;
    List<String> liste = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        System.out.println("Entrer une chaîne.");
        s = in.readLine();
        str = s.split("\\s+");
        liste = Arrays.asList(str);
    }
    return liste;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static ArrayList<String> lireArrayListString(int n) throws IOException
{
    InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(isr);
    String s;
    String [] str;
    ArrayList<String> liste=new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Entrer une chaîne.");
        s=in.readLine();
        str=s.split("\\s+");
        liste=(ArrayList<String>) Arrays.asList(str);
        
    }
    return liste;
}
```

}

Comment: here, i've put an ArrayList<String> after liste=

Comment: and before Arrays.asList(str);

Comment: but there's an exception when i enter a blockchain

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to class java.util.ArrayList (java.util.Arrays$ArrayList and java.util.ArrayList are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
 at nfa032.application.ArrayListUtils.lireArrayListString(ArrayListUtils.java:26)
 at nfa032.application.Main.main(Main.java:27)

Comment: Arrays.asList() does not return an ArrayList<>, but it returns a List<> (The super type of ArrayList). If you want to use Arrays.asList, you need to change the type of liste to List<String>